# Java link event to event handler

Tags: java, events

I'm working on a GUI library for my game, and I'm trying to find a good way to link events from GUI elements (for example a click-event from a button) to a event handler.

Say I have a button called MyButton.
I would use the following code to set it up (incomplete, just for demonstration):

```
Button MyButton = new Button();
MyButton.SetParent(MyContainer);
MyButton.SetText("Text inside my button!");
MyButton.SetTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Now this code would be called in one of my gamestates, and what I would like to do is something like this:

```
MyButton.OnClick(MyButtonClickEvent);

public void MyButtonClickEvent(EventArgs event) {

}
```

The structure of my gamestates and containers and elements are:

GameEngine->GameState->Container->Elements

What would be the closest solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not have methods as first-class functions, i.e., the language does not provide references to a method which you could pass around like you can in other languages. Your best bet for a construction like the one outlined in your question is to use reflection.

```java
import java.lang.NoSuchMethodException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyButton {
    private Object onClickObject;
    private Method onClickMethod;

    public void OnClick(Object object, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        OnClick(object, object.getClass().getMethod(methodName));
    }

    public void OnClick(Object object, Method method) {
        this.onClickObject = object;
        this.onClickMethod = method;
    }

    // MyButton calls this method every time the button is clicked, in
    // order to inform the external event handler about it
    protected void onClick() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        onClickMethod.invoke(onClickObject);
    }
}
```

But also note that *because* methods are no first-class citizens, the above is not the canonical way to implement event listeners in Java. Instead, the Java-way would be to define an interface with a callback method, maybe like this:

```
public interface ButtonListener {
    public void OnClick();
}
```

(This is assuming you don't have to pass any parameters to the event handler. Usually, this cannot be assumed, thus in addition to a `ButtonListener`, you'd also have a `ButtonEvent` which encapsulates the parameters and which is passed to the method(s) defined in the interface.)

Then if you write a class that is interested in receiving events whenever a certain button is clicked, that class would have to implement `ButtonListener`. In turn, the `MyButton` class would have to provide a method to register listeners:

```
public MyButton {
    protected List<ButtonListener> buttonListeners;

    public void addButtonListener(ButtonListener listener) {
       ...
    }

    public void removeButtonListener(ButtonListener listener) {
       ...
    }

    protected void fireButtonEvent() {
       ...
    }
}
```

I'm sure you've seen that pattern in the Java standard class library quite a bit, especially in `java.awt` and `javax.swing` -- see for instance `java.awt.event.ActionListener`, which is what AWT uses for button events.